# Redirect subdomain to port [nginx/flask]

Tags: nginx

I know that this is a common question, and there are answers for the same, but the reason I ask this question is because I do not know how to approach the solution. Depending on the way I decide to do it, the solution I can pick changes. Anyways,

I have an AWS EC2 instance. My DNS is handled by Route53 and I own example.com. Currently, on my instance, there are two services running:

```
example.com:80 [nginx/php/wordpress]
example.com:8142 [flask]
```

What I want to do is, make `app.example.com` point to `example.com:8142`. How exactly do I go about doing this? I am pretty sure that I will have to point `app.example.com` to the same IP as `example.com`, since it is the same box that will be serving it. And, nginx will be the first one to handle these requests at port 80. Is there a way with which I can make nginx forward all requests to localhost:8142?

Is there a better way that I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You could add a virtual host for app.example.com that listens on port 80 then proxy pass all requests to flask:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8142;
    }   
}
```

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to do this in Apache, to no avail. It was faster for me (on Digital Ocean) to create a new droplet, install the LEMP stack, configure the server, clone my application, and write these 7 lines of code than ALL of the hours I wasted trying to figure it out on Apache. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @ColeTierney  How can I pass subdomain (app.) to flask while using proxy_pass?

Comment: @AliKhosro You could try adding a custom header: `proxy_set_header X-Subdomain app;`

Comment: Could you tell me which file should I add the setting to?

Comment: @user1024, it is typically found here: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf  Usually that config file will include others which might be a better location for your settings. Depends on the setup. You could also just add your own include statement to nginx.conf and put your file in /etc/nginx. Nginx will look there for included files there.

Comment: After doing it,  `app.example.com` still point to the `example.com`. Is it  because I resolve the  `app.example.com` to server IP ?

Comment: @rosefun I would start with my exact example. If it works, start incrementally adding back the bits that you need; testing after each change. This should help narrow down the problem.

Comment: How does this even work? Once *.example.com is resolved to whatever IP, how can the server know which subdomain was used to access it?

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect your domain to a certain port. This depends on the web service you are using -Nginx/Apache. If you are using Nginx, you’ll need to do add a server block to your Nginx’s website config. This can be achieved by using the bellow

```
location /{
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8142/;
}
```

If you are using Apache, you have two options, the first one is to add a redirection rule in your website’s .htaccess and the second one would be to do it directly in the Apache’s Vhost file. I like using the first option. In your .htaccess file, you can add the following rule

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect to 3000 if current port is not 3000 and "some-prefix/" is matched
RewriteRule ^/(.*[^/])/?$ http://blabla:3000/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

If you want to use Apache’s Vhost file, I’ll recommend going through the following tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it with apache.

```
$cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/app.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.example.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8142/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8142/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have ubuntu 16 and nginx with two NodeJS instances, one for front, one for admin.
In, I have:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

I've added:

server {
...
location / {
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
}

```
location /admin {
    rewrite ^/admin(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
}

location /other {
    rewrite ^/other(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
}
...
```

}

I've used this to have access for admin.