# Shiny server and nginx subdomain

Tags: nginx, shiny, shiny-server

I have configured shiny server ok and I cannot redirect *localhost:3838* to *shiny.mywebsite.com*

I followed this [Redirect subdomain to port [nginx/flask]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649444/redirect-subdomain-to-port-nginx-flask) and RStudio guides but no success.

I tried

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name shiny.mywebsite.com;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3838;
    }
}
```

and

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name shiny.mywebsite.com;

    root /shiny;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/shiny.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/shiny.error.log;

    location / {
        index index.html;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

to be put in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/shiny.conf` and just can access *localhost:3838* but no *shiny.mywebsite.com*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare port 80 in `nginx` configuration file and not the `shiny-server.conf` I was confused at the start too.

*My shiny-server.conf*

```
# Instruct Shiny Server to run applications as the user "shiny"
run_as shiny;

server {

    listen 3838;
  location / {

    site_dir /home/shiny/ShinyApps;

    log_dir /home/shiny/logs;
    directory_index on;
  }
}
```

*My server within sites-enabled/default*.

Note that your website will be under `/var/www/shiny.mywebsite.com` directory. Then your shiny apps will be accessible via `shiny.mywebsite.com/shiny/YourApps`as we set up a proxy pass below.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/shiny.mywebsite.com;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html;

    server_name asemenov.com;

    location /shiny/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3838/;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```