# Multiple Sub-Domains on a single server. Docker + NGINX @ EC2

Tags: docker

I have multiple NGNIX-uWSGI based Django Applications deployed using Docker and hosted in EC2 (currently at different ports like 81, 82, ...). Now I wish to add in sub-domains to this such that sub1.domain.com and sub2.domain.com will both work from the same EC2 instance.

I am fine with multiple ports, BUT they dont work via DNS settings. 
sub1.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4:81
sub2.domain.com -> 1.2.3.4:82

**What I cannot do**

1. Multiple IPs [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944368/1897935): allocation of a new ip for each deployed sub-domain is not possible.
2. NGINX Proxy [ref](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy): This looks like the ideal solution BUT this is not maintained by an org like Docker or NGINX, so I am un-sure of the security and reliability.

**What I am considering:**

1. I am considering to write my own NGINX reverse proxy, similar to [Apache Multiple Sub Domains With One IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837978/apache-multiple-sub-domains-with-one-ip-address) BUT then the flow is will via multiple proxies since already there is an NGINX-uWSGI proxy via the Tech Stack

Answer (score 0):

you can use nginx upstream

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com       weight=5;
    server backend2.example.com:8080;
    server unix:/tmp/backend3;

    server backup1.example.com:8080   backup;
    server backup2.example.com:8080   backup;
}

server {

  server_name sub.test.com www.sub.test.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend;
    }
}
```